# Sum Column of Data where two rows are calculated before summing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with multiple columns

```
Code    Events    Time    AVG
A       1         1       1
B       2         2       1
C       10        5       2
```

I need to sum the events and total rows, but when it comes to a specific codes (B and C) I need to divide the events by two then include that number in the sum.

so the above output would be

```
TotalEvents    TotalTime
7              4.5
```

Total Events = 1 + (2/2) + (10/2) = 7

Total Time = 1+ (2/2) + (5/2) = 4.5

Any assistance is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Are you familiar with `CASE  ... END` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(case when code in ('B', 'C') then events / 2.0 else events end) as total_events,
       sum(case when code in ('B', 'C') then time / 2.0 else time end) as total_time
from t;
```

Comment: Totally!!  I was trying Case When, but I was noobishly putting the sum inside the case when statements.  Just never dawned on me to wrap the whole case when in the sum().  Thank you.